# Create specific bean dependant on property

Tags: java, spring

Lets say i have two beans:

`class MyBean implements BeanInterface(){}`

`class MyBean2 implements BeanInterface(){}`

And if specific property exists, i want to create `MyBean`, otherwise I want to create `MyBean2()`. How can i do this?

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "property.validation")
public BeanInterface beanInterface() {
    return new MyBean();
}
```

works if I want to create `MyBean` if property exists, but how do I create `MyBean2` if it doesn't?

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MyBean.class)
public BeanInterface beanInterface() {
    return new MyBean2();
}
```

complains that method with same name exists, and if i understand it correctly, the methods name need to be camelCase name of the bean.

How do i do this?

Thanks

//edit i tried:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "property.validation")
@Order(1)
public BeanInterface beanInterface() {
    return new MyBean();
}

@Bean("beanInterface")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MyBean.class)
@Order(2)
public BeanInterface beanInterface() {
    return new MyBean2();
}
```

but it didnt work, second bean is not getting created when property is missing.

Comment: You can easily achieve this behaviour using multiple configurations with [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify bean name `@Bean("beanInterface")` then method name can be anything.

Comment: i tried it but the bean is not getting created if the first bean is not created, i updated question

Answer (score 0):

You have Java configuration at your hands, so use that to your advantage. Not everything needs annotations to be fixed.

```java
@Bean
public BeanInterface myBean(Environment env) {
    String validation = env.getProperty("property.validation", String.class);
    return validation != null ? new MyBean(validation) : new MyBean2();
}
```

The name of the method doesn't matter it can be anything you like.

Answer (score -2):

Spring and Spring boot provide a a following solution: If you need to choose one implementation of the interface at runtime, than you inject all implementations and choose appropriate one at runtime. Assuming that you have an interface `DataSource` with multiple implementations here is how you inject them all:

```
@Autowired
private List<DataSource> dataSources;
```

You can read about this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026785/injecting-multiple-implementations-to-a-single-service-in-spring).
This is a standard solution, but I really don't like it as it is waistful to inject all implementations. So, I wrote a feature that is available as part of MgntUtils open-source library. That feature allows you to create a static factory per each interface, and once you add any implementation of that interface declared as a Bean, that implementation will be added automatically at start up into a relevant factory. So, instead of injecting all implementations in your class you at runtime take from the factory needed implementation. I think it is much more elegant solution, and it has been battle-tested and it works well. Here is Javadoc that explains the concept and has a detailed example on how to use it: [Lifecycle management](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/package-summary.html). Also here is the article that describes this feature in detail: [Non-intrusive access to "Orphaned" Beans in Spring framework](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/non-intrusive-access-orphaned-beans-spring-framework-michael-gantman/). The library is available as [Maven artifact at Maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) ad also on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) including javadoc and source code. In the source code there is a working example on how to use this feature

Comment: He wants to create only 1 not 2. Also creating "orphaned" beans can even lead to excessive bean creation for which configuration is needed but not wanted (because it isn't used).